# Change contents of list box by checkbox

Tags: javascript

I want to change the dynamic list box but I have no idea what to do.

When checkbox is checked
I want to change the contents of the list box.

```js
// getPageFileData -> Data acquisition with Ajax..
var retData = getPageFileData(productSeq, 3);

var linkArray = [{text:"Select Page", value:""}];
for (var i = 0; i < retData.PageList.length; i++) {
  linkArray.push({ text: retData.PageList[i].page_title, value:   retData.PageList[i].page_id });
}

// set linkArray
linkCustomLinkCtrl = {
  disabled: data.customType && data.customType == "2" ? false : true,
  name: 'customLink',
  type: 'listbox',
  label: 'CustomLink',
  values: linkArray
};


linkCustomLinkOtherCtrl = {
  disabled: data.customType && data.customType == "2" ? false : true,
  name: 'customLinkCheck',
  type: 'checkbox',
  checked: false,
  text: 'OtherProduct',
  onclick: function (e) {
    if (e.control.value()) {
      var retData = getPageFileData("", 3);
      var linkArray = [{ text: "Select Page", value: "", type: "menuitem" }];
      for (var i = 0; i < retData.PageList.length; i++) {
        linkArray.push({ text: retData.PageList[i].page_title, value: retData.PageList[i].page_id, type: "menuitem" });
      }
      var replaceSelect = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < linkArray.length; i++) {
        replaceSelect.push(linkArray[i]);
      }
      // -------------------------------------
      // Is not it like this?
      win.find("#customLink")[0]._values = replaceSelect;
      // -------------------------------------

      console.dir(win.find("#customLink"));
    }
  }
}
```

Is not it the way to rewrite `_values` in the first place?
I am sorry in my poor English..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know where to set it correctly.
I set it up as below and it was done.

```
var linkList = win.find("#customLink")[0];
if (linkList.menu) {
    linkList.value(null);
    linkList.menu = null;
    linkList.settings.menu = replaceSelect;
}
linkList._values = replaceSelect;
linkList.settings.values = replaceSelect;
linkList.state.data.menu = replaceSelect;
```

Is this correct??
Tentatively, the problem was solved.